# Merge multiple dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I try to merge multiple new dataFrames in a main one.
Suppose main dataframe:

```
      key1           key2
0   0.365803    0.259112
1   0.086869    0.589834
2   0.269619    0.183644
3   0.755826    0.045187
4   0.204009    0.669371
```

And I try to merge the 2 following datasets within the main one,
New data1:

```
        key1    key2    new feature
0   0.365803    0.259112    info1
```

New data2:

```
        key1    key2    new feature
0   0.204009    0.669371    info2
```

Expected result:

```
       key1       key2  new feature
0   0.365803    0.259112    info1
1   0.776945    0.780978    NaN
2   0.275891    0.114998    NaN
3   0.667057    0.373029    NaN
4   0.204009    0.669371    info2
```

What I tried:

```
test = test.merge(data1, left_on=['key1', 'key2'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how='left')
test = test.merge(data2, left_on=['key1', 'key2'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how='left')
```

Works well for the first one, but not for the second, the result I get:

```
        key1    key2    new feature_x   new feature_y
0   0.365803    0.259112    info1      NaN
1   0.776945    0.780978    NaN        NaN
2   0.275891    0.114998    NaN        NaN
3   0.667057    0.373029    NaN        NaN
4   0.204009    0.669371    NaN       info2
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrame`s together and then `merge`:

```
dat = pd.concat([data1, data2], ignore_index=True)
```

Or:

```
dat = data1.append(data2, ignore_index=True)

print (dat)
       key1      key2 new feature
0  0.365803  0.259112       info1
1  0.204009  0.669371       info2
```

---

```
#if same joined columns names better is only on parameter
df = test.merge(dat, on=['key1', 'key2'], how='left')

print (df)
       key1      key2 new feature
0  0.365803  0.259112       info1
1  0.086869  0.589834         NaN
2  0.269619  0.183644         NaN
3  0.755826  0.045187         NaN
4  0.204009  0.669371       info2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) instead:

```
# create new column and set index
res = test.assign(newfeature=None).set_index(['key1', 'key2'])

# update with new data sequentially
res.update(data1.set_index(['key1', 'key2']))
res.update(data2.set_index(['key1', 'key2']))

# reset index to recover columns
res = res.reset_index()

print(res)

       key1      key2 newfeature
0  0.365803  0.259112      info1
1  0.086869  0.589834       None
2  0.269619  0.183644       None
3  0.755826  0.045187       None
4  0.204009  0.669371      info2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the data frames to the same index and use simple `loc`

```
df  = df.set_index(["key1", "key2"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["key1", "key2"])
```

Then

```
df.loc[:, "new_feature"] = df2['new_feature']
```